Why ring expansion doesn't take place here?
I was solving the 28th July JEE Mains 2022 Shift-2 paper (JEE Mains is an entrance exam conducted in India), when I encountered this particular question.
The question is as follows: The major product in the given reaction is,

Now, the answer keys uploaded in the internet and the official answer key by the testing agency says that the correct option is (C)
And the websites giving solution to this problem gives following reaction sequence,

Now, my question is, Why doesn't the 5-membered carbocation ring expand and form a 6-membered ring?
Am I missing something or is there anything wrong in the question?

5-membered rings are the kinetic product, formin much faster than [6] rings. When the cation is trapped by Br- the system is locked.

@Waylander But before trapping by Br-, the cation ring can expand, right? 5-membered ring is formed faster, but before gaining Br-, to attain more stability, 6-membered ring have to be formed, right?

I think there is a competition between capture by Br- and ring expansion which Br- capture wines

@Waylander Ok, so can you please tell me in which conditions ring expansion (or more general rearrangement) would be preferred over capturing of external group?

Protonation with an acid whose anion is much less nucelophilic such as perchloric acid

@Waylander Thank you so much for help!!

While 6-membered rings do have less ring strain than 5-membered rings, 5-membered rings form faster because they are kinetically favored in intermolecular cyclization reactions.
In an oversimplification (full of technical errors):
The vinylic carbon that will form a 5-membered ring can get closer to the carbocation more often than the vinylic carbon that will form a 6-membered ring can, thus making the vinylic carbon that will form a 5-membered ring have a higher "effective concentration" than the vinylic carbon that will form a 6-membered ring.
Generally, once formed, the 5-membered ring won't expand into 6-membered rings because such ring expansions are slow compared to the destruction of the carbocation (think of it like why two hydride shifts don't generally occur to form a more stable carbocation).
Furthermore, in this case, ring expansion into a cyclohexane ring would create a secondary carbocation compared to the tertiary carbocation when the 5-membered ring existed, making the ring expansion even more kinetically unfavorable.
